# react-markdown with react-syntax-highligther code render bug

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I am using react-markdown with react-syntax-highlihter to do some code syntax higlighting in markdown content.

```
[object Object], requests

url = ,[object Object],
header = {
    ,[object Object],: ,[object Object],,
    ,[object Object],: ,[object Object],
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

,[object Object], response.status_code == ,[object Object],:
    ,[object Object],(,[object Object],)
    data = response.json()  ,[object Object],
,[object Object],:
    ,[object Object],(,[object Object],, response.status_code)
```

the output code looks like this instead of showing the actual code.
I am using react-markdown v8.0.7 (downgraded from 9.0.10 and react-syntax-highlighter v15.5.0

Can someone help please?

Suggest fix to this problem.

Comment: You also should provide some Code, not only the output in order to be able to help you. For me it looks like, you're passing in objects instead of strings.